# UICollectionView visibleCells returns nil

Tags: objective-c, uicollectionview

Although `UICollectionViewCell`s is displayed, `[collectionView visibleCells]` returns nil.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
    self.collectionView = [[UICollectionView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 568) collectionViewLayout:flowLayout];
    self.collectionView.delegate = self;
    self.collectionView.dataSource = self;
    [self.collectionView registerClass:[CustomCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    [self.view addSubview:self.collectionView];

    NSLog(@"%d", [[self.collectionView visibleCells] count]);
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CustomCell* cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    return cell;
}
```

Do you have any idea?

Comment: Try move the NSLog from viewDidLoad to viewDidAppeare.

Comment: Did your code go trough `collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:` before your call to `visibleCells`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in your view controller

```
- (void) viewDidLayoutSubviews {
   NSLog(@"%d", [[self.collectionView visibleCells] count]);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The issue is caused by reload has not been finished. 
The solution is ：
1. [collectionView reloadData];
2. **[collectionView layoutIfNeeded];
3. the get your - > [collectionView visibleCells];

Answer (score 0):

Try add this:

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
    collectionView?.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
}
```